# Google Map Coords escaping

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, google-maps

This is the problem: 45°38'14.07"

How can escape it (Struts action read an XLS that made a string. This string is the param of array in js).

Or without escaping.. how can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question, but in JSON notation, this would be escaped as:

```
"45\u0xb038'14.07\""
```

Notice that I've used the unicode for the angle (code: 0xb0 according to http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html) and escape the double quote.  Hopefully that's helpful.  Depending on how you're going to use it, you could also represent the degree symbol as `°` for input into HTML.

So if initializing an array, you'd want something like this:

```
var myArray = [ "45\u0xb038'14.07\"" ];
```